# Mysql not returning all results

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to fetch some data using only one query. I need to fetch one shop, which can have several modules (or possibly none), for each module I need one record in modules to exist.

My problem is getting all shop_modules enabled except just the first one? Is this possible without splitting it in two queries?

Thanks in advance

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
      s.*, sm.config, m.internal_name 
    FROM shops s 
    LEFT JOIN shop_modules sm ON sm.shop_id = s.id 
    INNER JOIN modules m ON m.id = sm.module_id WHERE s.domain = ?";

$shop = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql, array($subdomain));
```

Comment: Do you want the modules as separate ros, or do you want them concatenated together? so one row would be `'shop', 'module1, module2, module3','internal name'` (3 columns) or do you want to be able to loop through the modules?

Comment: If your query above does not result in `shop1, module1`, `shop1, module2`, `shop1, module3` then it might be your inner join causing the latter modules not to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer to a similiar question on another site: "*A database query produces a result set, which is exactly like a flat file -- it has rows and columns*" - e.g. what I'm asking is not possible without splitting the query in two!